# Delimiting space + comma

Tags: php

I know that if I would for example use this code:

```
<?php
    $tags = "hello, bye, test";
    $tags = explode(",", $tags);
?>
```

It would seperate by commas. But I would still have spaces left there and I want to save those values in the database without those spaces. How do I do this?

Comment: [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/str_getcsv) commonly trumps `explode`.

Comment: You can either `trim()` the result in `array_map()`, or use `preg_split('/,\s+/', $str)` instead. (but I like `str_getcsv()` better if you have PHP 5.3+)

Comment: Im checking out str_getcsv() thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the spaces are always present a quick solution is to use:

```
$tags = "hello, bye, test";
$tags = explode(", ", $tags);
```

Otherwise (as Michael suggested) you can trim the values:

```
$tags = "hello, bye, test";
$tags = explode(",", $tags);
$tags = array_map('trim', $tags);
```

Comment: Thanks this looks like easy to use would you suggest str_getcsv or array_map method?

Comment: @Xegano It depends on the data. If say, it is a bunch of tags then the above would be fine. If it is more like csv data (i.e. you could have things like `"Hello","World",Foo,"I has a comma,"`. Then marios suggestion of `str_getcsv` is better.

Answer (score 1):

What about using explode with `", "` as delimiter?

```
$tags = "hello, bye, test";
$atags = explode(", ", $tags);
```

Gets this:

```
print_r($atags);
Array ( [0] => hello [1] => bye [2] => test )
```

I know it is not the most beautiful solution, but it also works.

**Edit**
From the comment *"Yes but it should work on both ways like the tag system here on stackoverflow. For example it should split "hello, bye" as well as "hello,bye" and "hello bye" – Xegano 1 min ago"*,

In this case, you should only use explode with `","` and then trim whitespaces surrounding the words. Something like this:

```
$tags = "hello, bye, test";
$atags = explode(",", $tags);
$atags = array_map('trim', $atags);
```

Comment: Yes but it should work on both ways like the tag system here on stackoverflow. For example it should split "hello, bye" as well as "hello,bye" and "hello bye"

Comment: In this case it is different, @Xegano. I edit my answer to take this in account.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As Michael pointed out, we dont want to replace all whitespace, only that following a comma. We can use array map to run each item in the exploded array through trim.

```
<?php
    $tags = "hello, bye, test";
    $tags = array_map( 
        function($s){ 
            return trim($s); 
        }, 
        explode(",", $tags)
    );
?>
```